# How to Resolve "unknown Android version on device."

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, samsung-mobile

==Development Environment==

- Eclipse Version: 3.7.2
- Ntt Docomo's Samsung Galaxy S with Android (unrooted) 2.3.3
- ndk version: r8
- Computer: Windows 7

==Question==
I have an ndk project built against android API level 9 (2.3.1).
When trying to Debug as "Android Native Application", Eclipse often displays 
"Unknown Android version on device." in the Console and refuses to launch the application.

1. What logic is Eclipse using to generate that message?
2. What steps must one take to resolve it?

Other Android cell phones I work with do not have this problem.

Comment: Is the device you're testing on rooted?